# How do i get the Instance of the class when i use winrt::static_lifetime?

Tags: c++-winrt

I switched from C++/CX to C++/winrt not long ago and I'm currently stuck because I want to create a singleton winrt-class. I read about winrt::static_lifetime (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/static-lifetime), but they don't provide any code example on how to use it.
So my Question is how do I get the Instance of the class with this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Why don't you implement it just like you would implement any other C++ singleton? Provide a `static` class member, and return a function local instance object with static storage duration (see e.g. [Modern C++ Singleton Template](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/173929)). [Magic statics](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm) make this thread-safe, too.

Comment: Yeah i do it right now and it woks just fine but for these winrt classes this is not a good practice because i have to define the class from the code behind and cannot use the XAML definition. Also i have to go into the implementation namespace to call the Instance function because i cannot define the get_instance function in the MIDL3 file. Finally why shouldn't I do it, the intended way?

Comment: Well, sure, any object with static storage duration is - by definition - a singleton. That doesn't require every singleton to have static storage duration, though. And it doesn't look like `static_lifetime` does what you think it does: It is a marker struct, whose sole purpose is to have a name for a unique type. It is used to control template instantiation, and is only ever evaluated in the [make_factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/make) function template, seemingly as an optimization. Besides, you can declare a static factory method in MIDL 3.

Comment: Ok i see. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`winrt::static_lifetime` specifies that the factory is a singleton so you basically need to implement the singleton instance as a property of the (now singleton) factory.

Namely:

```
namespace Foo::implementation {
    struct Foo : FooT<Foo> {
        Foo() {
        }

        static Foo Singleton() {
            auto fooFactory = winrt::make<factory_implementation::Foo>();
            return fooFactory->Singleton();
        }
    };
}

namespace Foo::factory_implementation {
    // specifies the factory is a singleton
    struct Foo : FooT<Foo, implementation::Foo, winrt::static_lifetime> 
    {
        Foo Singleton() {
            slim_lock_guard lock{ m_lock };
            if (!m_singleton) {
                m_singleton = winrt::make<Foo>();
            }
            return m_singleton;
        }

    private:
        winrt::slim_mutex m_lock;
        Foo m_singleton;
    };
}
```

So why is this preferred at all in comparison to something like:

```
static Foo Singleton() {
    static auto single = winrt::make<Foo>();
    return single;
}
```

The reason to do this is because process statics may be destroyed after RoUninitialize resulting in a crash. winrt::static_lifetime basically puts the factory into `CoreApplication.Properties` which is uninitialized safely before the process does RoUninitialize. It's basically for the same reason why storing legacy COM objects into process globals needed to be avoided in the past.